# Site logo not showing, no home page

Tags: logo

My site logo is uploaded in the theme customizer, and I can see it on all of the pages when I'm previewing the site in the customizer. But it doesn't show on the live site. I read in one of the previous answers that about logo not displaying that the logo draws from the home page. This may be the problem because I deleted the home page. So now how can I get the logo to show?

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress Development. I'm having a little trouble understanding what you are asking. What do you mean by "I deleted the home page" do you mean a page/post that was being served for the home page? Would you please edit your question to clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many different causes for this issue. The easiest way to determine the cause is to inspect the logo element on the front end of your website. See how the HTML structure has been rendered, what might have gone wrong? Is the image source okay? Are there any CSS interferences? There are lots of things to check, but that's the first thing to do—[inspect the element](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-inspect) to help figure out the cause.